# Creating a 'Modal' slide down - has to be modal where end user can not select anything else

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to create a 'modal' slide down panel for a page. I have no problem with creating the slide down itself its the modal part I'm having the issue with.

I've played around with a few plugins such as simplemodal and blockui, and I've figured out how to create a modal pop up with no issue, now creating a modal slide down...., that I haven't quite figured out.

How can I get the needed informations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using jQuery UI's dialog.

```
$('#modal-content').dialog({ show: 'blind', modal: true});
```

Comment: Not the effect I'm looking for. With this I guess I can use the position option to set it to the top and try to make it look like a slide down panel but this doesn't really look like a slide down and it isn't modal. They shouldn't be able to select anything outside of the slide down panel.